# Make Neural Network run faster (MATLAB)

Tags: performance, matlab, neural-network

I have a MATLAB code for neural network and it takes around 3 mins to train the network.(it trains around 85 files).
When I use the `profile viewer` it says that `trainlm` has a self time 143.166s which 83.3% of that time comes from `dWB = -(jj+ii*mu) \ je;`

Is there a way of making it faster? Should I use data binning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That one line is a solution of a linear system of equations. The limit here is the number of unknowns, so the size of your network which defines the number of unknowns.

No, you cannot really reduce that time easily, unless you are willing to reduce the number of unknowns, or buy/find a faster computer.

Comment: oh.. my supervisor told me that I can use Data binning but I really don't know what data binning actually does and if it will help me reduce the time.. thanks :)

Comment: Then maybe you need to talk to your supervisor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked whether you can somehow parallelize your code using `parfor` or the parallel computing toolbox in general?

Comment: well no.. I don't really know how do to that :/

Comment: Are you using for loops? If so, try you use `parfor`loops. The following link could help you:http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: I do..But it seems that it takes a long time not at the loop but when I have `net = train(net,y,T');`

Comment: To jump on the questions above: data bining is nothing else than just bining your data, so summarizing data in bins to have less data to handle at ones or at all.

Comment: oh..so by binning my data I might lose some data?

Comment: It depends on how you bin your data. If bin it and then summarize for every bin, yes, you will lose some data. If you bin to use different cores on your computer, then you will not lose data. If you can somehow use `parfor` that would actual help, since every core would would run independently each loop. So your `net=...`would run on all cores in parallel.

Comment: also is there any similar command with `parfor` but for while loops??

Comment: Each iteration of FOR loops are often
independent of the others, which means they can be
parallelized. WHILE loops, on the other hand, tend to
terminate depending on the result of some internal
computation in the iteration. Which makes it hard to
parallelize. Cited from Matlab Central

Comment: btw avoiding `for`and `while` at all would also speed up your script. Functions like `arrayfun` etc are much more efficient...